# AJAX calls in Laravel - Like button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

There are many questions about this already on StackOverflow so I will try to make this question specific, but also useful to others.

I have an article with some buttons as follows:

[image]

With the Like button (the heart), I did this:

```
<!-- The individual items -->
<div class="interaction-item">
    <a href="{{ action('LikeController@likeArticle', $article->id) }}" class="interactor" role="button" tabindex="0">
        <div class="icon-block">
            <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

So that when you click on the heart it calls my `LikeController` with a specific method.

**LikeController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\Like;
use App\Article;
use App\Event;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LikeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display all liked content for this user
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        $articles = $user->likedArticles()->get();

        $articleCount = count($articles);

        return view('pages.likes.index', compact('articles', 'articleCount'));
    }

    /**
     * Handle the liking of an Article
     *
     * @param int $id
     * @return void
     */
    public function likeArticle($id)
    {
        // here you can check if product exists or is valid or whatever
        $this->handleLike(Article::class, $id);

        return redirect()->back();
    }

    /**
     * Handle the liking of an Event
     *
     * @param int $id
     * @return void
     */
    public function likeEvent($id)
    {
        // here you can check if product exists or is valid or whatever
        $this->handleLike(Post::class, $id);

        return redirect()->back();
    }

    /**
     * Handle a Like
     * First we check the existing Likes as well as the currently soft deleted likes.
     * If this Like doesn't exist, we create it using the given fields
     *
     *
     * @param [type] $type
     * @param [type] $id
     * @return void
     */
    public function handleLike($type, $id)
    {
        $existingLike = Like::withTrashed()
        ->whereLikeableType($type)
        ->whereLikeableId($id)
        ->whereUserUsername(Auth::user()->username)
        ->first();

        if (is_null($existingLike)) {
            // This user hasn't liked this thing so we add it
            Like::create([
                'user_username' => Auth::user()->username,
                'likeable_id'   => $id,
                'likeable_type' => $type,
            ]);
        } else {
            // As existingLike was not null we need to effectively un-like this thing
            if (is_null($existingLike->deleted_at)) {
                $existingLike->delete();
            } else {
                $existingLike->restore();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, essentially you click the button, the Like is registered and the page is refreshed.

What I'd actually like is this: when the button is pressed the request is acknowledged and then a class is assigned to the button making it darker, similar to Facebook, Twitter and the like.

I am not using any JavaScript frontend framework so I thought I would go with `AJAX` and bring in a framework in the future.

To make an AJAX call I know starts like this:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: './likes/articles/' + id,
        data: "",
        success: function() {
            console.log("Simple example");
        }
    })
});
```

So I can call the route with an AJAX request, but two questions come to mind.

1. PHP is server side so how do I get the ID of the current article? In PHP I know you could do `$id = $article->id` but it'd be stupid to believe a PHP variable could be used in JavaScript. However I was thinking of `url: 'article/likes/{{ $article->id }}',`

   2. I know on success I can manipulate the DOM but how can I ensure the button stays pressed?

I'm researching more as we speak so will add to this question as I go.

**An update**

```
$( ".like" ).click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '{{ action("LikeController@likeArticle", $article->id) }}',
            type: 'GET',
            date: "",
            success: function (result) {

            },
            error: function (result) {

            }
        });  
    });

    </script>
```

This calls the route successfully but I still need to jig the button.

Answer (score 0):

First think about how is your view being generated. PHP will go first output all variables and whatever routes you have in there and sent a response with ALL your variables already inside the view.

After that when the user is in the view, your anchor will already have the url you need. So you would only need to do something like this:

```
$(".interactor").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();// you dont want your anchor to redirect so prevent it
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        // blade.php already loaded with contents we need, so we just need to
        // select the anchor attribute href with js.
        url: $('.interactor').attr('href'),
        success: function() {
           console.log("Simple example");
        }
    })
});
```

As you see please keep in mind that using php&js together like you tried is reaaaaaally odd

Comment: you should unless you want to create another ajax specifically to retrieve the info you need for the url, which doesn't make a lot of sense. I think it's the most reasonable way to approach it

Comment: I mean, I literally just want the user to press a button and that button triggers the liking of an article

Comment: You mean that button triggering an ajax, which is basically what you are doing? xD I don't understand what you dont find reasonable about doing it like this,

Comment: Keep in mind that I prevent the anchor event so the user won't get redirected and it will 'feel' like just pressing the button

Comment: To be honest, my biggest peave is how on earth do you keep the button a fixed colour when it has been liked? I was going to wrap the button in an if else, like, if not liked -> this colour and vice versa

Comment: on your success function you can add a css class to the button that trigerred the event, and in blade.php when you print the view you should could check with an if/else if the user already liked or not that button

Comment: I'll try this and get back to you... as I want this to be a somewhat useful question to the community, but so far I've been a dunce about it

Comment: In my view I have the ability to do this

if($article->isLiked)
Unlike this 
elseLike this awesome product!
        @endif

Comment: A question ins't for developing a feature out of the scope of the question itself but whatever dood X)

Comment: I'll post my solution